# no voice in second incoming call linphonne-ios callkit

Tags: swift, iphone, callkit, linphone

We have a custom app that uses the liblinphone sdk and everything is working perfectly. The issue lies when the iPhone screen is locked and a call comes in through CallKit, the first call is answered and works perfectly, however if another VoIP call comes in through CallKit during this scenario and the End & Accept button is pressed the first call is ended successfully but when the second call is being answered there is not any audio . The app thinks it has successfully answered the call but the sip stack never stood up the call. It appears that because of how CallKit works with this scenario where the first call is ended BEFORE the incoming call is answered that there is a brief period where there is not an active call, however there is a pending INVITE. Is there a way to get around this in linphone?

Comment: can you please tell me how you achieve the callkit support in linphone? 
I am using the latest source code from linphone they said it support for callkit while i run the app in real device its not working , any help will be helpful for me.
Thanks